# How to jump 10minute forward in audio when click on next button?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have tried some logics but not getting any success. I am working on a Audio player application. And I am using **MediaPlayer** class to play audio files from sdcard. Now let me explain situation where I am facing issue.

Situation:

There is a 60min audio file. Now I want to implement functionality like when click on *NEXT Button* audio should jump 10min forward. And if i click on *PREVIOUS Button* audio should jump 10min backward. For example,
right now if my audio is on 5min and I click on next button audio should jump on 15 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friends i got the answer i am posting it here so it can be useful for others...it is simple logic

```
private int TIME_INTERVAL = 60000;
private MediaPlayer mp;
```

In onCreate method just initialise media player object

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
```

//On next button click 1minute jump from current position

```
case R.id.imageNext:
                int currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                mp.seekTo(currentDuration + TIME_INTERVAL);
                break;
            case R.id.imagePrevious:
                int currentDuration1 = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                mp.seekTo(currentDuration1 - TIME_INTERVAL);
 private int TIME_INTERVAL = 60000;
```